# Infinite loop in a calculator Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, do-while

I've written this bit of code to serve as a little calculator because I was bored, but since it appears to be stuck in an infinite loop it's bothering me. I've added a few comments to describe what each bit is meant to do.

```
print "Enter your current humanity: "
current = gets.chomp("Enter Current Humanity: ") #Has user input current humanity
print "Enter the value of an AI bandit kill: "
bandit = gets.chomp ("What is the value of an AI bandit?") #Has user specify bandit's worth
kills = 0 #sets the needed kills to 0, to allow proper counting
hero = 5000

if Integer(current) >= Integer(hero)
  puts "You're already a hero"
elsif Integer(current) < Integer(hero)
  while Integer(current) < Integer(hero) do #SHOULD continue going until current is over 5000
    Integer(current) + Integer(bandit) #ERROR: "possibly useless use of + void context" What?
    Integer(kills) + 1
  end
else #everything under here probably will be removed anyhow
  puts "Something went wrong"
  puts "perhaps you've placed a non-integer in the inputs?"
end
```

EDIT: After reading and responding to the answers I've found that the loops were caused by my lack of understanding in Ruby resulting in variables not being modified, and comparison errors in my lack of using .to_i

I thank everyone for their assistance.

Comment: Are you trying to increment `current` by `bandit`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add bandit to current until current is 5000(the value of hero) after a load of googling, and errors about them being incomparable I added the Integer() to them and it seems to work a bit, at least.

Comment: You can also remove the `while` and use a division, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is to do with coercing the variables into an intger. There's a lot of needless code here, and the conversion you are doing does not alter the original variable.

```
hero = 10
Integer(hero) + 1
# => 11
puts hero
# => 10 # notice hero is still 10, and not 11
```

Instead, you can just convert to an int when using gets:

```
bandit.to_i
```

Then your code would look something like this:

```
if current >= hero
  puts "You're already a hero"
elsif current < hero
  while current < hero
    current += bandit # not sure what you want to do here, frankly
    kills += 1
  end
else
  puts "Something went wrong"
  puts "perhaps you've placed a non-integer in the inputs?"
end
```

The infinite loop is no longer an issue because you are mutating `current`. And the warning `possibly useless use of +` would go away for the same reason.

Comment: With the current += bandit, I'm trying to add the value of a bandit (which is meant to be varying, and should be specified each time the code is executed) So I wanted the loop to check current and then add the value until it was at least 5000

Comment: @Sneak_Stealth I gathered that, but forgot to take the comment off. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop because you never change any of your variables.

```
print "Enter your current humanity: "
current = gets.chomp("Enter Current Humanity: ").to_i
print "Enter the value of an AI bandit kill: "
bandit = gets.chomp("What is the value of an AI bandit?").to_i
kills = 0
hero = 5000

if current >= hero
  puts "You're already a hero"
else
  while current < hero
    current += bandit
    kills += 1
  end
end
```

This code is probably closer to what you want though I can't say I fully understand the point and the tracking of the kills doesn't really do anything since it's never used.

Comment: I simply neglected to include the little bit after the final end that was supposed to print out the value of kills along with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're using calls to the `Integer` conversion everywhere, the problem becomes more obvious if it's only done where needed:

```
print "Enter your current humanity: "
current = gets.chomp("Enter Current Humanity: ").to_i
print "Enter the value of an AI bandit kill: "
bandit = gets.chomp("What is the value of an AI bandit?").to_i
kills = 0
hero = 5000

if current >= hero
  puts "You're already a hero"
elsif current < hero
  while current < hero do
    current + bandit
    kills
  end
else
  puts "Something went wrong"
  puts "perhaps you've placed a non-integer in the inputs?"
end
```

As you can see, you're doing `current + bandit` in your while loop, but nothing is actually done with the result of that, and no variable is changed as a result of it.

What you'd want to do on that line is:

```
current += bandit
kills += 1
```

Which increments `current` with the value of `bandit`.

Note that I've used `to_i` to convert the string to an int, as this prevents an error when an empty string is entered by the user.

Comment: After looking at these changes and adjusting the code accordingly, on line 5 it throws an error "humanity.rb:5:in `chomp': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)"

Comment: There's a space that shouldn't be there. I've fixed it.